# ModalPopupExtender, GridView, and IE6 - Disappearing Header Image

Tags: css, gridview, modalpopupextender

I've got a GridView inside a Panel being shown by a ModalPopupExtender.  I am testing this in IE6 (corporate standard).  The gridview has a CSS class applied to it.  The portion of the class that applies to the header is:

```
.myGrid .head
{
    background-image:url('../Images/GridHeader.gif');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    color:White;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The problem is that when the ModalPopupExtender fires, the image for the background does not show.  The text is white and bold, but the background image is not there.

Any ideas on how to get the background image to show.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the toolkit are you using.  Their September update fixed a lot of IE 6 related issues to modal pop-ups.